# Where does a @Nullable annotation refer to in case of a varargs parameter?

Tags: java-8, type-annotation

For the following signature:

```
public static String format(final String pattern, final @Nullable Object... arguments)
```

Where does the @Nullable annotation refer to? To the array or to its elements? Is there a possibility to annotate both options (array/elements)?

Are there differences between Java 7 and Java 8 (type annotations)?

Comment: Type annotations were added in Java 8 as part of JSR 308.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since there still is no standard `@Nullable` annotation, you are using an annotation of a 3rd party library, thus it depends on how it is declared. Pre-Java 8 annotations aren’t type annotations as that feature doesn’t exist in older versions. Hence, with these annotations you are always annotating the *parameter* rather than its type. This is usually interpreted by frameworks as “the parameter can be `null`” which would be the array reference, though the frameworks may treat varargs specially, but there is no standard mandating a particular behavior.

When you are using a real Java 8 type annotation, i.e. an annotation with `@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)`, the outcome in best explained by using the ordinary array declaration:

```
@Nullable ElementType  []
```

declares an array of `@Nullable ElementType`, read nullable elements whereas

```
ElementType  @Nullable []
```

declare a nullable array type.

thus, the declaration

```
public static String format(final String pattern, final @Nullable Object... arguments)
```

implies that the *elements* can be `null` whereas

```
public static String format(final String pattern, final Object @Nullable... arguments)
```

declares that the *array reference* may be `null`. Of course, you may combine them to declare that *both*, the elements or the array itself, can be `null`

```
public static String format(String pattern, @Nullable Object @Nullable ... arguments)
```

As said, to use these options, you need an annotation type which is really declared as a Java 8 type annotation. Then, to enforce the described semantics you need an up-to-date checker framework implementation compatible with Java 8 type annotations.

Comment: The difference is also documented here (by way of the array syntax): http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-using_null_type_annotations.htm&cp=1_3_9_1_3&anchor=compatibility